# Define key type for object in `for-in`

Tags: typescript

I have an object type:

```js
interface ShortUrlParam {
    openid: string;
    avatar: string;
    nickname: string;
}

const param: ShortUrlParam = {
    openid: 'abc123',
    avatar: '',
    nickname: 'wenzi'
}

let query = '';
for(let key in param) {
    query += `&${key}=${encodeURIComponent(param[key])}`; // error tip
}
```

in param[key], error tip is:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ShortUrlParam'.
>    No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ShortUrlParam'.ts(7053)

I have two programmes, but not perfect.

#### 1. redefine interface ShortUrlParam

```js
interface ShortUrlParam {
    openid: string;
    avatar: string;
    nickname: string;
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

#### 2. param as any

```js
for(let key in param) {
    query += `&${key}=${encodeURIComponent((param as any)[key])}`;
}
```

my question is there has any better solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For better or worse, TypeScript does not let you give a type annotation to a variable introduced in a `for..in` loop [(see microsoft/TypeScript#3500)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3500).  This is justified by reasons of soundness; in TypeScript, object types are *open* and not *exact* [(see microsoft/TypeScript#12936)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), so it's always possible for an object to have unknown extra properties you weren't expecting.  All we really know about `key` in `for (let key in param) {}` is that `key` is a `string`: we can't safely narrow it to `keyof ShortUrlParam`.

Except of course we can because you created it yourself as an object literal several lines earlier and we know we didn't add extra properties. One [suggested workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3500#issuecomment-388883320) if you want to use a type annotation is to declare the variable before the loop and give it the type you want:

```
let key: keyof ShortUrlParam; // this is allowed
for (key in param) {
  query += `&${key}=${encodeURIComponent(param[key])}`;  // no error
}
```

This works with no error (but beware if it turns out someone has added an unexpected property to `param` when you weren't looking).

---

A similar approach is to leave the loop declaration alone but to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that `key` is of type `keyof ShortUrlParam`:

```
for (let key in param) {
  query += `&${key}=${encodeURIComponent(param[key as keyof ShortUrlParam])}`; // okay
}
```

---

I'd say both of those are somewhat safer than using `any`, since at least you'd catch errors if someone added a property to `ShortUrlParam` that isn't accepted by `encodeURIComponent()`.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoAsD2UwFUoA2ACnFHALbIDeAsAFDLKYAOEIwAJgFzIDOYUUAHMA3PUZwAbnDCke-QSFHjk7BAGsQFCPIHCxdAL716CTCH7JmpCjwzY8hEmUoBeaipZtOPAORwAIwQARgAmAGZfABoVKRk5ZF9olTVNbT8AdzYAL2BfemM6egIIMGQARwBXaABPZHckgxKy9QganlaazBg0LBx8YhtyEWQAelHkMHRgXmQZ5DgCAkwsjnoYbGQACk65kCshgEoPBgrqqDqAancAAwAyABIqTsNXJ7YzDghcACUASQAwphyMxzGwwFtrC4ANqdAC6h0MNxG4yY6jgNQKJjoGyg22ayF2oAOLmOtFOVVqyGuyHuTxebyoH0wX1+gOBoJA4MhQ1hbQWs063V6DgGzgoCKRKImmHRmKM9CAA)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly less safe than jcalz's answer, but useful for type hints in case you don't have a specific type definition handy (because you didn't declare an object literal one line before).
You can infer it instead of falling back to any. Just don't fall back to any...

Also the js heap in the scope of a for loop is destroyed every iteration, so we can use const instead of let to assert that key won't change. If you dó change the key you loop over, just use a regular old for-loop to avoid messy code.

Generic example:

```js
for (const key in thing) {
  doThings(key as keyof typeof thing)
}
```

Example with the context of your question:

```js
for (const key in param) {
  query += `&${key}=${encodeURIComponent(param[key as keyof typeof param])}`
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
for(var i=0;i<param.length; i++) {
  let key  =   param[i];
  query += `&${key}=${encodeURIComponent((param as any)[key])}`;
}
```

Comment: param is an object type, this solution can work? and, this is like my second programme, I want to del `any`

Comment: This answer does not address the question.  `param` has no `length` property, nor does it have a numeric index signature.