# How's 'for...in' loop doesn't infer the right type of the 'key' in the 'object'

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form

I need to modify type of my data from string to number before querying. I am using a loop to modify each value of the data object.

```js
const onSubmit = async (data: { [key in DeclaredInfos]: string }) => {
    const dataFormatted: { [key in DeclaredInfos]: number } | {} = {}
    for (const key in data) {
      dataFormatted[key] = data[key]
    }
  }
```

got this error, and you see 'key' in recorded to be a string whereas I defined the type 'DeclaredInfos' and so you should be one of these caracters chains

```js
type DeclaredInfos = "action-stocks" | "assets" | "expenses" | "revenues" | "liabilities"
```

```
const key: string
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ "action-stocks": string; assets: string; expenses: string; revenues: string; liabilities: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ "action-stocks": string; assets: string; expenses: string; revenues: string; liabilities: string; }'.ts(7053)
```

please advise something I don't want to use 'any'.

Thanks

**EDIT**, after 2 first responses:
Thank you for your answers. Both helped me
I used them combined

```js
const onSubmit = async (data: { [key in DeclaredInfos]: string }) => {
    const dataFormatted: { [key in DeclaredInfos]?: number } = {}

    for (const key in data) {
      dataFormatted[key as DeclaredInfos] = Number(data[key as DeclaredInfos])
    }
  }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59656330/327598

Answer (score 1):

Another user has referenced [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59656330/3275980), which you should definitely read. I'm going to address that issue along with a couple others in this answer.

First of all, let's borrow from the linked answer to coerce `key` into type `DeclaredInfos`:

```
let key: DeclaredInfos;
for (key in data) {
  dataFormatted[key] = data[key];
}
```

You can't give a type annotation to a variable introduced in a `for..in` loop (again, see the linked answer for details), but this is an acceptable workaround.

Secondly, rather than saying

```
const dataFormatted: { [key in DeclaredInfos]: number } | {} = {};
```

You can more succinctly say

```
const dataFormatted: { [key in DeclaredInfos]?: number } = {};
```

This indicates that all keys will be of type `DeclaredInfos`, but also that not necessarily all `DeclaredInfos` will appear as keys.

Finally, you need to choose between `string` and `number` for your value types. You declare `data` as `{ [key in DeclaredInfos]: string }` and `dataFormatted` as `{ [key in DeclaredInfos]?: number }` (after the change outlined above). Without an explict transformation from `string` to `number`, these don't match.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a type assertion

```
const onSubmit = async (data: { [key in DeclaredInfos]: string }) => {
    const dataFormatted: { [key in DeclaredInfos]: number } | {} = {}
    for (const key in data) {
      dataFormatted[key as DeclaredInfos] = data[key as DeclaredInfos]
    }
  }
```