# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type for satisfies Record

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to get the loop through an obj and get the value based in the key but I keep getting this error.

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

here's a code example of what I'm doing:

```
type ObjType = Record<string, any>
const obj ={
    item1: "test",
    item2: "test2"
} satisfies ObjType

for (let key in obj){
    const newKey = key as keyof ObjType
    console.log(obj[newKey])
}
```

The error disappears when I do this:

```
const obj: ObjType ={
    item1: "test",
    item2: "test2"
}
```

but I would really prefer to have the intelligence and proper checking that comes with `satisfies`

Comment: apologies, just edited. I'm asserting a type to newKey as the key of ObjType since for loops typecast the keys as strings

Comment: You can't have it both ways; either you widen `obj` to `ObjType` and can index with any `string` key, or you leave it narrow and unsafely narrow key to `keyof typeof obj` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mxyzzW). Which way do you prefer?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! key typeof obj is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

[The `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) checks a value against a type without *widening* it to that type, so when you write this:

```
type ObjType = Record<string, any>

const obj = {
    item1: "test",
    item2: "test2"
} satisfies ObjType;
```

You end up with a value `obj` of type

```
/* const obj: {
    item1: string;
    item2: string;
} */
```

which has no special relationship with `ObjType`.  While `ObjType` has a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) allowing you to index into it with any `string`-valued key, the type `{item1: string; item2: string}` does not.  You can only index into it with either the `"item1"` or `"item2"` keys.  That is, the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `"item1" | "item2"`.

Thus the obvious way to alter your code is to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `newKey` is of type `"item1" | "item2"`, which we can programmatically derive from `obj` as `keyof typeof obj` (using the [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) and the [`typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) type operators):

```
for (let key in obj) {
    const newKey = key as keyof typeof obj;
    console.log(obj[newKey])
}
```

Note that `key` is intentionally inferred as `string` and not `keyof typeof obj`; it's possible for objects to have more properties than the compiler knows about.  So to narrow `newKey` from `string` to `keyof typeof obj` we need that type assertion, because it's potentially unsafe.  See [Define key type for object in `for-in`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59656190/2887218) for more information.  But in your case we know it's safe in practice because `obj`'s type is derived from an object literal so we know it doesn't contain any extra properties.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwCrmgXigJQgYwPYBOAJgDwDOwBAlgHYDmANFAIY0gB8AUJ-jRVHkRQMAb05QJUKsAgBbAIwAuKACIZFFQ3GTpcgEzK1ECnpWcAvlDLNgVMgDMqx2IhSQA3JwD0AKii9+QQRlMUkpGQVlCmp6TzDdWQMrSlo6T0sfL257QigACgAbCGAoAGsIECkaAUQASihQyQCSmggAdwBpCuEy7uYyXpA8eyhQSGGahG0JALwigDoCvDo8oIBtVs6KgF1ai24gA)