# Iterate and change values of dynamic properties

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to iterate through unknown properties of an object (created out of a class).
I found [a webpage](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-access-object-property-dynamically) that helped me a lot.

So my code is working fine without a method:

```
export class TranslateEntry {
    datum: string = 'Datum';
    sport: string = 'Sport';
    leistung: string = 'Leistung';
    einheit: string = 'Einheit';
    constructor()
    {
        type ObjectKey = keyof TranslateEntry;
        for( let key in this )
        {      
          this[ key as ObjectKey ] ="T" + this[ key as ObjectKey ] + "T";
        }
    }
}
```

But if i add a method, the code is not working anymore:

```
export class TranslateEntry {    
    datum: string = 'Datum';
    sport: string = 'Sport';
    leistung: string = 'Leistung';
    einheit: string = 'Einheit';
    constructor()
    {
        type ObjectKey = keyof TranslateEntry;
        for( let key in this )
        {      
          this[ key as ObjectKey ] ="T" + this[ key as ObjectKey ] + "T";
        }
    }

    test()
    {
        
    }
}
```

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string & (() => void)'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '() => void'
```

I understand the concept of union of literal types, as described here:
[What does "keyof typeof" mean in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377365/what-does-keyof-typeof-mean-in-typescript)

But I can't fix my problem.

Comment: The constructor code is setting the value of every property to the value of the property as a string surrounded by the letter T. How is that supposed to work with a function? How is TypeScript supposed to interpret `this.test = "TundefinedT"`, when it knows that `test` is supposed to be a function? What problem are you trying to fix?

Comment: TS doesn't really know how to distinguish instance properties from prototype properties at the type level, so that's why it's worried that `"test"` might be one of the keys.  If you're willing to assert that `key` will never correspond to function-valued properties, you can change `ObjectKey` to be [something like this](https://tsplay.dev/N9VG1m).  Since you're apparently already willing to assert that `key as ObjectKey` then maybe that will work for you.  Does that fully address the question?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am  I missing?

Comment: 1. If i make a console.log( key ) inside the for "test" will never gone shown.
2. I tried the solution with Object.keys( this ). But this is also a problem. It looks like the problem only in the allocation of this[key]. 
"test" is also not shown in the Object.keys( this ) array.

Comment: @jcalz
That works !! Great.
 I am really extremely curious to hear what you have to say on this matter

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the type system does cannot currently represent [the ownership or enumerability of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties).  The [`keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) returns all keys of the type, as intended (see [microsoft/TypeScript#18133](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18133)).  So `keyof TranslateEntry` includes `"test"`... and there's no `ownKeyof` operator that would know how to include own properties like `"datum"` but exclude inherited properties like `"test"`.  There's a longstanding feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#9726](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9726) to support such a distinction, but it's not part of the language (and not likely to be unless it gets a lot more community interest).

That means you'll need to work around it somehow.  You're already working around the issue where object types are not *sealed*, so `for (let k in obj) {}` and `Object.keys(obj)` are not guaranteed to return only the keys TypeScript knows about (see [TypeScript: Object.keys return string[]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52856496/2887218) and [Define key type for object in `for-in`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59656190/2887218) for more information).  That is, you're using the [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) `key as ObjectKey`.  So you might as well stretch the workaround further and write `key as "datum" | "sport" | "leistung" | "einheit"`.

If you don't want to write that out manually and you are willing to assume that all function-valued properties are inherited, you can rewrite `ObjectKey` to exclude such keys, possibly like this:

```
export class TranslateEntry {
    datum: string = 'Datum';
    sport: string = 'Sport';
    leistung: string = 'Leistung';
    einheit: string = 'Einheit';
    constructor() {
        type NonFunctionProp = keyof { [K in keyof TranslateEntry as
            TranslateEntry[K] extends Function ? never : K]: any };
        // type NonFunctionProp = "datum" | "sport" | "leistung" | "einheit"
        for (let key in this) {
            this[key as NonFunctionProp] = "T" + this[key as NonFunctionProp] + "T";
        }
    }
    test() {
    }
}
```

Here I've renamed `ObjectKey` to `NonFunctionProp` to make it obvious what we're doing.  The implementation uses the key filtering feature of [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to suppress property keys whose value type is assignable to `Function`.  You can see that it evaluates to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `"datum" | "sport" | "leistung" | "einheit"` automatically.

And now the code compiles with no error.

---

Note again that those assertions are you making assumptions about what's going to happen.  If someone comes along and adds a function-valued *instance property* to your class, like this:

```
class TranslateEntry {
    datum: string = 'Datum';
    sport: string = 'Sport';
    leistung: string = 'Leistung';
    einheit: string = 'Einheit';
    oopsie = () => { } // <-- uh oh
    constructor() {
        type NonFunctionProp = keyof { [K in keyof TranslateEntry as
            TranslateEntry[K] extends Function ? never : K]: any };
        for (let key in this) {
            this[key as NonFunctionProp] = "T" + this[key as NonFunctionProp] + "T";
        }
    }
    test() {
    }
}
```

then the code still  compiles with no error but there's an accident waiting to happen as soon as you try to use that instance property later:

```
const t = new TranslateEntry();
console.log(t.oopsie); //  "T() => { }T" 
t.oopsie(); // no compiler error, but
//  RUNTIME ERROR: TypeError: t.oopsie is not a function
```

Oops, a function has been turned into a string and we didn't catch it.  Maybe this sort of situation is unlikely to happen, but you should be aware of your assumptions so that it's a calculated risk and not an unanticipated problem.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.2.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqBOYB2FwBcCmBRJb4E9oBvAKGnOgBMw0BXAWwC5oI8BLJAc2gF5oByACI0G-ANxkKEAA4B7eGmat4Hbn34BlOQvGTyIDG1a0uS9l14CAMoeNddFaIaQALQ4pbm1ArBzds0BwpZWWkINgxLAAoASl4APmJoAF89aGBZFDxaYDR5WOI0xzR8aUiAOUyAMRNctkyABXhQywBrDHxZADMkgG0AaWgOaHbOnoRkVBpsXAJoSCLHCgmUdBm8fAGAXScAD0wkShgapDrM6AB+aCQMADcMeGhmfq3mZEJkiSWKAHof6BKZWglSQJzOSCaLT4ACJqHR6NDoAAfaDQmTyNCIlHQgxGOhcLGo5z+TGLchdeTQKIGNAjDpDJAAlxGOKkb7fNDMiC9UbzGAgsFoeoQ5rSHYw2CIgDUTKMPPpkGB1VqQsaop2Muhkq+7NSjj1FEwrAKbIoqVSJAyWQBlhuAHc4IhVtMcBtYhIrRBZAYAHQgWScKJoH0hMIRGJiaB-chago8RJEFKS6CAPg3AFS7JGDofCGHdUf+D2a8AAhACQ6Ec0MYEhZLSwNAuirhUA)

Answer (score 0):

idk whats your problem statement but first of all, its impressive and something i couldn't think of probably if i were to given the same problem statement

Usually TS does this thing called setting types for basic things like variables and functions even if you don't assign types specifically

it understood those variables are 'string' and function (that doesn't return anything) as 'void'

---

Edited :

But i am thinking that you should give arrow functions a try.

Instead of test(){}  go for  test : any = () => {}

this will work i think, let me know if it does work

and you can remove 'T' prefix and suffix if you don't need in that string

you will be having 4 strings and 1 function (test) inside an object

here is the implementation in SerService
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9ud2z?file=src%2Fser.service.ts

Comment: No sorry, the same Problem.

Comment: you can use any to skip out this TS error for now

('T' + this[key as ObjectKey] + 'T') as any

You might get a result like this

{
datum: "TDatumT"
einheit: "TEinheitT"
leistung: "TLeistungT"
sport: "TSportT"
test: "T() => {\n }T"
}
Check this SerService if u are interested
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9ud2z?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fser.service.ts

Comment: u need a test key with function as value or just string ?

Comment: sorry i couldnt get if there is a reason behind T
but try this
test: any = () => {};
and u have 4 string 
1 function with test as object key
and u can also access this function

This is just a workaround since we are using 'any'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).